# Pandas groupby indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I am a bit confused by an aspect of the `groupby` in `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3], b=[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]))
g = df.groupby(by=['a', 'b'])
```

The groups in `g` are the tuples formed by the values of `a` and `b`. As I grouped by the two columns, there are no more columns left.

I would have guessed that the kind of aggregation I can perform are like `.size()` for getting the group size.

```
In [2]: g.groups
Out[2]: 
{(1, 1): Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 1): Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 2): Int64Index([3], dtype='int64'),
 (3, 3): Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')}
```

What I do not understand is that I can do `g['b'].groups`.

```
In [3]: g.b.groups
Out[3]: 
{(1, 1): Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 1): Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 2): Int64Index([3], dtype='int64'),
 (3, 3): Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')}
```

What does the key `b` mean in the groups?

Thanks,
F.

Comment: `g` is a `GroupBy` object, you can access one or more columns and perform groupby operations on those.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what it means by doing for example:

```
>>> g.sum()
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

and with the columns selected:

```
>>> g.b.sum()
a  b
1  1    2
2  1    1
   2    2
3  3    3
```

The groups are the same but the columns where you apply the computation are different.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I understand that `g` is a `GroupBy` object and that I can perform operations on available columns. In fact I do that all the time.

What I do not fully understand is the fact that `b` was used for grouping. Usually the aggregation operation is performed on a column not used for grouping like `g.c.sum()` if `c` was a third column. But in the example `b` has been used for grouping. What does it mean to group by `a` and `b` and then aggregate on `b`?

Comment: It's like you would copy the index `b` values inside a new column b. In this case, for the value a = 1, b = 1, you have 2 entries, the index b will be 1 but the sum will be 2.

Comment: I see that's the copy part that I was missing. Indeed, `g.a.sum()` and `g.b.sum()` lead to two different results as if `a` and `b` were respectively copied. Thank you for the explanation.